# What is the solution for OpenCV haar training infinite loop when overfitting?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I run Haar training in openCV 2.4.3.

1. I have 10 negative images and about 30 positive (I know that it is small amount).
2. positive samples are organized in 'vec' file and negative (background ) images are described by text file which stores the path's of the images.
3. With such a small amount of images a perfect solution exists (all of the background images classified as false and the real samples as true).

When this perfect solution found, openCV enters an infinite loop inside `icvGetHaarTrainingData()` function.

It wants to find background images on which the cascade fails but there are no more such images so this function is stuck in `for(;;)` loop forever.

`icvGetBackgroundImage()` function, called in this loop, just keeps loading the same images from hard-disk which are rejected by the cascade.

Does someone know of a patch, or a bug fix I can apply to solve this problem?

One possible fix, I came up with, is to let `icvGetBackgroundImage()` load each file only once since if it was rejected by the cascade once it would be rejected always. But this is a wrong tweak since this same function is used for generating 'vec' files in `cvCreateSamples()` and in this scenario we do want it to load the same file few times.

Second possible fix - use negative examples in vec file (like positive examples) instead of info path format. This is a way to overcome infinite loop by not activating the problematic callback, but the result is an openCV error that causes a crash. It happens when negative 'vec' file reaches EOF.

Meanwhile I solved those 2 bugs (infinite loop and crash) by changing directly the source code of openCV and recompiling the binaries. I will submit my changes to openCV committee soon. But I can't believe that I am the only one who bumped into such problem...

Comment: can you post your code? this would make the troubleshooting easier.

Comment: OpenCV haar training is compiled as exe and I am activating exe file from command prompt. There is no code of mine. The problem is inside openCV. I call this exe file using the following line: P:\Bin\opencv_haartraining.exe -data P:\zDB_CC\TrainData\cv -vec P:\zDB_CC\TrainData\cv.vec -bg P:\zDB_CC\TrainData\cv_neg.txt -npos 10 -nneg 30 -nstages 5 -nsplits 1 -mem 1000 -nonsym  -minhitrate 0.99799 -maxfalsealarm 0.039811 -mode BASIC -bt GAB -maxtreesplits 0 -minpos 500 -w 16 -h 24

Comment: Can you post your changes to the source code here? I'm currently having the same problem as you have.

Comment: Sorry man. Its difficult. I made changes in few files. Write me an Email to DanielHsH at gmail and I will send you the changes + documentation of what I changed. Now It works like a magic!  By the way. In order to train cascade for a good detection you need at least 1 million of negative examples. supposing each round you choose 1000 examples and  on average cascade rejects 50% of the negatives on each stage after 10 stages you will run out of ~million examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting here The fixed code. Please note that an original openCV license is applied to it as well.
https://github.com/DanielHsH/OpenCV-HaarTraining-BugFix